# How do i submit a form by email at the click of a button?

Tags: html, outlook

I have a script written to send an email of a completed form when I click a button but it doesn't work, here's the code:

```
<button type= "button" onclick= form action="mailto:Myemail@mail.co.uk">Submit</button>
```

where have I gone wrong? I'm aware that I don't have Outlook Express so if form action does not work without it, is there an alternative?

Comment: Try this:
<input type="button" value="Submit" onClick="parent.location='mailto:invalid@email.com';">

Comment: You are using the word "script" very loosely. This html needs to run on a server, post the form data to an aspx or php page (or any other server side language), and that server side script needs to send the email to a mail server you have access to. If you configure the mail server yourself, it will probably require relay.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> where have I gone wrong?

- You are trying to use [`mailto:` as a form action](http://isolani.co.uk/articles/mailto.html). It doesn't work.
- You are trying to specify your `action` on a `<button>` instead of on a `<form>`
- You are using a `type="button"` (which is for JavaScript binding) instead of `type="submit"`

> is there an alternative?

Submit to a server side program, written in the language of your choice (that is supported by your server), and have it send the email. Third party hosted options are available.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to open the email client on button click use this:

```
<input type="button" value="Submit" onClick="parent.location='Myemail@mail.co.uk';">
```

You do not need form action for that.

Another option is to write some kind of server side code that sends the email directly without having to open up the email client. You can write the code in variety of languages like PHP, ASP.NET etc.

Comment: is there a way to get this to send to the email client automatically?

Comment: Well, no this just opens up the email client. If you want to send an email, where exactly do you plan to write the subject and the body?

Comment: Im thinking about writing it to a .txt file and sending it via Exchange pick up to the email client